# Using rounddown in Java

Tags: java, double, rounding

I know there is a way to make my program not round up, but I can't figure it out and every time I try it throws different errors at me. So my code minus all the attempts at rounding it down is

```
    public class TheoryTest {
      public static void main (String[] args) {
      System.out.printf("%-15s%-15s%5s%-15s%-15s\n", "Feet", "Meter", "|    ", "Meter", "Feet");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");

        double foot = 1.0; double meter = 20.0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; foot++, meter += 5, i++) {
          System.out.printf("%-15.1f%-15.3f%5s%-15.1f%-15.3f\n", foot, footToMeter(foot), "|    ", meter,
              meterToFoot(meter));
        }
      }

      public static double footToMeter(double foot) {
        Math.floor(return 0.305*foot);
      }

      public static double meterToFoot(double meter) { 
        Math.floor(return);           
        return 3.2787*meter;
      }
    }
```

error: illegal start of expression
    Math.floor(return 0.305*foot);

error: ';' expected
    Math.floor(return 0.305*foot);

error: illegal start of expression
    Math.floor(return 0.305*foot);

error: ';' expected
    Math.floor(return 0.305*foot);

error: illegal start of expression
    Math.floor(return);

error: ';' expected
    Math.floor(return);

6 errors
C:\Users\Shannon Reynolds\Desktop\try\LabChapter69\nbproject\build-impl.xml:930: The following error occurred while executing this line:

C:\Users\Shannon Reynolds\Desktop\try\LabChapter69\nbproject\build-impl.xml:270: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Comment: When you say round down do you mean Math.floor(double a)? Give us an example including output and expected output. Just edit your question.

Comment: The only rounding I currently see is from the formatter statements, and they should round as you would expect.

Comment: `double myVal = BigDecimal.valueOf(doubleValueToRound).setScale(intPrecisionYouWant, RoundingMode.DOWN).doubleValue();`

Comment: Why are you putting "return" in brackets?

Comment: You could always cast to int and back to double and it would have the same effect as `Math.floor()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statements are off... the functions that return double should return a value, not a return in the parameter list.

change:

```
  public static double footToMeter(double foot) {
    Math.floor(return 0.305*foot);
  }

  public static double meterToFoot(double meter) { 
    Math.floor(return);           
    return 3.2787*meter;
  }
```

...to:

```
  public static double footToMeter(double foot) {
    return Math.floor(0.305*foot);
  }

  public static double meterToFoot(double meter) { 
    return 3.2787*meter;
  }
```